# How to get data from Wordpress and pass into javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am working on a website and I am now wanting to do one thing but not sure how to achieve it.

I have posts of post type named "Flat rate trips" in which each trip(post) there is 1 meta field named "Pick up".

I want to get all "Pick up" value and then pass to javascript variable like this (to use in header.php):

```
var pickup= [ { value: "United States",
                label: "United States",
                id: "1"    },    
              { value: "Japan",
                label: "Japan",       
                id: "2"    },];
```

And for this "United States,1" and "Japan, 2" is two value of meta_field (pickup) and post_id.
Can anybody help me to achieve this thing?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem. But you may need to adjust post type and post meta names in the given code:

```
    $trips=get_posts(array("post_type"=>'flat_rate_trips','numberposts'=>-1));
    $jsdata='';
    foreach($trips as $trip){
    $data=explode(",",get_post_meta($trip->ID,'pick_up',true));
    if (empty($data[1])) continue;
    $jsdata.='{ value: "'.$data[0].'",
                    label: "'.$data[0].'",
                    id: "'.$trip->ID.'"    },';
    }

   echo 'var pickup= [ '.$jsdata.' ];';
```

Comment: Thanks Elvin.. I tried this but it returned as var pickup= [ ]; and how can I pass this as a Javascript variable after doing this. Thanks once again

Comment: I got the result after doing some changes. How can I make it a javascript variable now? Thanks

Comment: "How can I make it a javascript variable now?" - i already answered to this question. The given code is the answer. But if it doesn't bring data, it is another problem, you type wrong "post type" and "post meta" names.

Comment: remove this line to get more detailed results:  if (empty($data[1])) continue;

Comment: I solved the problem succesfully..Thanks Evlin very much for your solution.